# Vertically align image in div that uses padding-bottom to lock ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is using padding-bottom:100% to lock the aspect ratio of the div to 1:1 (for responsive purposes):

```
<div class="image-container">

</div>
```

css:

```
.image-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Now, I have an image inside of this container with width:100%. However, the image stays at the top and I can't use vertical-align:middle on the image.

Is there a way I can get this image centered vertically? JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g819gz2a/

**Unfortunately I will need this to work for not only IE 9 but the deadly IE 8**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do the following using `absolute` positioning:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g819gz2a/2/) 
*(in example background of image made green to show its centered)*

```
.container {
    width:300px;
}
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background:yellow;
}
img {
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0px);
}
```

And for older browsers:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g819gz2a/3/)

```
img {
    background: green;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know browser compatibility for transform: translate3d?

Comment: Unfortunately I will need this to work for not only IE 9 but the deadly IE 8 :(

Comment: You should have specified that in your question so that @dwreck08 did not waste his time!

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)